# How can I add a user keyword to the VS2013 TypeScript language text editor?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I need to add "self" as a "user keyword" but I cannot see to do this in VS2013. I would like it to be a user keyword for the TypeScript editor window.

I am making frequent use of "self" in my code.  Is there a way that I can add the word "self." as a keyword and have it appear in a different color in my TypeScript text editing window?

Here's an example of where I would use self and would like to have it highlighted:

```
class X {
    abc=1;
    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) {}
    doTask = () => {
        var self = this;      
        this.$http({
            xx
        })
        .success((data) => {
            self.abc = data
        })
    }
}
```

Update:

I have added a few lines to the question to more closely match the way I am using `self`.

Comment: Wait a moment, `self` is usually used in JS as a closure capture for `this`. Is that what you are using it for? You don't need it in typescript.

Comment: It's needed as one way to handle this in a callback function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471975/how-can-i-preserve-lexical-scope-in-typescript-with-a-callback-function/22569517#22569517

Comment: @Marilou as I stated in my answer in the question you mentioned, there is a way to avoid "self". If you use methods properly, you won't have to bother with it

Comment: I've not tested it, but you could try this: change the typescriptServices.js file in ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TypeScript. Look for the KeywordCompletions.keywords variable definition and add "self" in there. Restart VS.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 13 and I do not see this file.

Comment: I am sorry but none of the answers here are correct. Also note the question was about adding a user keyword but nobody gave any suggestions on this except Simon and I cannot find the file he mentioned.

Comment: Daily downvote rampage. Besides that of [aecend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25167077/2788872), **every single answer is completely off-topic**. I came here looking for _visual studio typescript add keyword_, yet almost every answer is a small beginners tutorial about the use of lexical scopes and ES6 arrow functions.

Answer (score 4):

This will work fine with a [lambda](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39):

```
class X {
    doTask = () => {    
        this.doJob({
            foo: "bar"
        }).success((data) => {
            this.abc = data;
        });
    }
}
```

It compiles to:

```
function X() {
    var _this = this;
    this.doTask = function () {
        _this.doJob({
            foo: "bar"
        }).success(function (data) {
            _this.abc = data;
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: I agree that it compiles and looks like it should work but I have been unable to get an example like yours to work correctly. If you have a few minutes I would really appreciate you showing me this in an example.

Comment: The modified version looks like it should work with TypeScript's lambdas too. Perhaps Angular is doing something strange when constructing the object using dependency injection.

Comment: Personally, in JavaScript I've started using _this instead of self, since self is already a global defined to equal the current frame, which could lead to strange bugs if say a `var self = this` line was missing.

Comment: I would like to use _this but because it's Typescript when I do that in the Typescript file I get an error: Error 429 Duplicate identifier '_this'. Compiler uses variable declaration '_this' to capture 'this' reference.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend trying ReSharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to extend the syntax highlighting options in VS2013. It's a 30-day trial, but if it does what you need then I'd say it's worth purchasing. Here's a link to the documentation for the extended color highlighting:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Syntax_Highlighting.html

From your question, it seems that all you're interested in doing is specifying another keyword to highlight so that it visually stands out in the code. ReSharper will allow you to easily do this.

Answer (score 1):

This is how would your class look like property written in TypeScript using methods. Then you would not need to bother with `self`.

```
class X {
    private abc: number = 1;

    public doTask(): void {
        this.doJob()
            .success((data) => this.processData(data));
    }

    private processData(data: any): void {
        this.abc = data.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I agree your idea is good. But I do have a few times where it may be a bit easier to use self. I have for example some methods like processData that are just one line methods. Being able to put them inline is good as I don't have to add to the number of methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code example to take better advantage of TypeScript and avoid the need to define a `self` variable. Consider the following.

```
class X {
    abc = 1;
    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) { }
    doTask() {
        this.$http({
            xx
        })
        .success(data => {
            this.abc = <number>data;
        });
    }
}
```

The body of `doTask` is defined in a function rather than a lambda. When TypeScript sees a function (named or anonymous), it uses it as the scope that inner `this` references should apply to. TypeScript implements this by creating a `_this` variable in the .js file at the function level, which mirrors the `self` variable you were looking to create by hand.

Just as it is important to use a function at the outer scope, it is important to use a lambda for the success handler. If you had coded the handler like the following, it would create a new "this scope", causing `_this` to not be generated.

```
    .success(function (data) {
        this.abc = <number>data; // Not desired behavior - creates a new abc variable
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry but when I copy this code exactly the this in the success (when I use a lambda) is still the Windows object at run time even though in the designer and in the js it looks like it should be the correct scope.