# call method from inside callback using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm having trouble calling a method from within another method in the same class in TypeScript.  I'm wanting to call the `routeTheRequest` method from inside the `onRequest` method, but I can't make it work.

**index.ts**

```
import server = require("./server");

new server.MyServer();
```

**server.ts**

```
import http = require("http");

export class MyServer{

    public constructor(){
        http.createServer(this.onRequest).listen(8888);
        console.log("Server has started.");
    }

    private onRequest(request: http.ServerRequest, response: http.ServerResponse){
        var path = request.url;

        this.routeTheRequest(path);  // *** how do i call routeTheRequest ?? ***

        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });      
        response.end();
    }

    private routeTheRequest(urlString: string): void{
        console.log("user requested : " + urlString);
    }
}
```

Using `this.routeTheRequest` doesn't work, `this` loses scope and refers to the `http.Server` object that `createServer` is returning.  I've tried pretty much all the different ways of calling `this` from these pages...

[How can I preserve lexical scope in TypeScript with a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471975/how-can-i-preserve-lexical-scope-in-typescript-with-a-callback-function)

[TypeScript "this" scoping issue when called in jquery callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627138/typescript-this-scoping-issue-when-called-in-jquery-callback/20627988#20627988)

A non-jQuery solution would be preferable.  Thanks

Comment: The fix from the accepted answer was covered in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by writing the `onRequest` method like this. Note, you shouldn't write all methods like this as it does cost some performance (it creates a new function for every instance instead of putting it on the prototype) but in this case that doesn't really matter.

```
class MyServer {
    private onRequest = (request: http.ServerRequest, response: http.ServerResponse) => {
        var path = request.url;

        this.routeTheRequest(path);  // *** how do i call routeTheRequest ?? ***

        response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });      
        response.end();
    }
}
```

Notice the lambda on the function.

Another way is writing:

```
http.createServer(this.onRequest.bind(this)).listen(8888);
```

edit:
I talked about that it does cost performance but the impact isn't that big, but what I actually meant by that was don't write every method this way (only the ones who need to capture `this` and are called by passing the method to a different function).

Comment: Yep. Just tested it and they both work.  Thankyou.  Do they both do the same thing, like behind the scenes ?  You say that it affects performance writing it this way, would this matter with something like a node.js server ?

Comment: Performance impact isn't that big, only when you create a lot of MyServer instances but I don't think that is the case. So you won't notice any difference. The bind methods is likely a bit slower then the first option (according to this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-performace).