# Setting context of "this" from another typescript class, using AngularJS dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm using a TypeScript class to define a controller in AngularJS:

```
class TrialsCtrl {
    constructor(private $scope: ITrialsScope, private ResourceServices: ResourceServices) {
        this.loadTrials();
    }

    loadTrials() {
        console.log("TrialsCtrl:", this);        
        this.Trial.query().then((result) => {
            this.$scope.Trials = result;
        });
    }

    remove(Trial: IRestTrial) {
        this.ResourceServices.remove(Trial, this.loadTrials);
    }
}
angular.module("app").controller("TrialsCtrl", TrialsCtrl);
```

I'm refactoring common controller methods into a service.

```
class ResourceServices {    
    public remove(resource, reload) {     
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
            resource.remove().then(() => {
                reload();
            });
        }
    }
}

angular.module("app").service("ResourceServices", ResourceServices);
```

The console log shows that `this` is referencing the window context when I want it to be `TrialsCtrl`. My problem is that the `reload()` method needs to run in the context of `TrialsCtrl`, so that it can access `this.Trial` and `this.$scope`. How can I tell the `reload()` method to set `this` as the `TrialsCtrl`? Or is there some other workaround I should be using for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
this.ResourceServices.remove(Trial, this.loadTrials.bind(this));
```

or

```
this.ResourceServices.remove(Trial, () => this.loadTrials());
```

Comment: `this.loadTrials.bind(this)` works, thanks! I tried `() => this.loadTrials` as well, but it seemed to never actually run the callback.

Comment: Ok, I've missed brackets in my second example it should be `this.ResourceServices.remove(Trial, () => this.loadTrials());`both methods should keep origin context for passed callback.

Answer (score 1):

For methods that are supposed to be passed as callbacks (as with `this.loadTrials`) it is preferable to define them as arrows,

```
loadTrials = () => { ... }
```

So they keep the context whether `Function.prototype.bind` is used or not.

Alternatively, a decorator may be used on the method (like [core-decorators @autobind](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators.js#autobind)) to bind a method while still defining it on class prototype:

```
@autobind
loadTrials() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works as well. As I was looking for answers I came across this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471975/how-can-i-preserve-lexical-scope-in-typescript-with-a-callback-function/21386201#21386201 Your answer is very similar to **Option 5**, presented in the second answer. Do you think these questions are similar enough to be considered duplicates?

Comment: Yes, they are. Almost every reasonable question has been already discussed on SO. Added a decorator solution, I'm quite sure it wasn't mentioned in the earlier question.