# Async and typeScript class method - Why no access to class property?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, typescript, async.js

Given a simple typeScript class:

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;

  constructor(message: string) {
    this.greeting = message;
  }

  greet() {
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
  }

  thisworks(input) {
    console.log("I am " + input) ;
  }

  doesNotWork(input) {
    return "Hi " + this.greeting +". I am " + input;
  }   
}
```

an array:

```
let myArray = ["Joe","William","Jack","Averell"];
```

and a function:

```
let myFunction = (name) => {
  let obj = new Greeter(name);
  console.log(obj.greet());
};
```

---

I can map the array and execute the function for each value:

```
async.map(
  myArray,
  myFunction
);
```

Or I can map the array and execute a class method with each value:

```
let myInput = new Greeter("John");

async.map(
  myArray,
  myInput.thisworks
);
```

---

But I cannot map the array, passing each value to a class method, and access the class property at the same time:

```
let myInput = new Greeter("Bill");

async.map(
  myArray,
  myInput.doesNotWork
);
```

---

**Can someone please explain why the last example does not work? And how to make it work?**

I expected the result with the last example to be:

```
Hi Bill. I am Joe
Hi Bill. I am William
Hi Bill. I am Jack
Hi Bill. I am Averell
```

Instead, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'greeting' of undefined
```

---

Here is [a plunk associated with this question](https://plnkr.co/edit/vVdLZZSE2UnrAOjHntgx?p=preview)

Comment: Basically the same scope problem as everyone gets. `myInput.doesNotWork` is called with a `this` which refers to something other than `myInput`. Either bind it to the correct context like `myInput.doesNotWork.bind(myInput)` or use a function call like `(item) => myInput.doesNotWork(item)`...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14471975/266535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with lexical `this`.

The solution is to make sure you bind `this` when the function is created or when the function is called.

### Bind `this` when function is created

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
      this.greeting = message;
    }

    doesNotWork = (input) => {
      console.log("Hi " + this.greeting +". I am " + input);
    }

}
```

OR

### Bind `this` at call site

```
let myInput = new Greeter("Bill");
async.map(
    myArray,
    myInput.doesNotWork.bind(myInput)
);
```