# Problem : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have property   `category = <CategoryModel>{};`
CategoryModel model is model is :

```
export class CategoryModel {
 public name: string;
 public description: string;
 public image: string;
 public products?: ProductModel[];


constructor(name: string, desciption: string, image: string = null, products: ProductModel[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desciption;
    this.image = image;
    this.products = products;
}
}
```

And I want to store  `category`in to Array `categoryList: CategoryModel[] = [];`
 with this code `this.categoryList.push(this.category);`
And I have error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null`.

This is post method where I want to store `category` in array and send to server.

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {


  category = <CategoryModel>{};


  //  category: CategoryModel[] = [];
  categoryList: CategoryModel[] = [];
  categoryProduct: ProductModel[];

  categoryForm: FormGroup;
  productForm: FormGroup;
  modalRef: BsModalRef;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private productsService: ProductsService, private dataStorageServiceService: DataStorageServiceService, private modalService: BsModalService, private adminService: AdminService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategory();
    this.initForm();
    console.log(this.categoryList);
  }

  getCategory() {
    this.dataStorageServiceService.getCategory()
      .subscribe(
        (cateogrys: CategoryModel[]) => {
          this.categoryList = cateogrys;
          console.log(this.categoryList)
        }
      );
  }


  storeCategoryList() {
    const nameCategory = this.categoryForm.value.name;
    const descriptionCategory = this.categoryForm.value.category;
    this.category.name = nameCategory;
    this.category.description = descriptionCategory;
    console.log(this.category);

    this.categoryList.push(this.category);
    this.dataStorageServiceService.storeCategoryList(this.categoryList).subscribe(

      (category: CategoryModel) => {
        category = this.category
        this.categoryList.push(category)
        console.log(this.categoryList)
      }

    )
}


  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }

  private initForm() {
    this.categoryForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'description': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'image': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    })

    this.productForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      'description': new FormControl(null, Validators.required)

    })

  }




}
```

Comment: Where/how exactly is `categoryList` defined? Where is `this.categoryList.push(this.category);` happening exactly? Please share that code because it's currently unclear.

Comment: I edit the post, you can see.

Comment: Sorry, still not seeing where you are doing `categoryList: CategoryModel[] = [];`. The error is indicating you are creating and attempting to access a variable outside the current available scope of the `class` or similar. Please update your code to show where/how you are initializing `categoryList`.

Comment: I shared whole class, you can see better.

Comment: Are you executing storeCategoryList from inside the modal?

Comment: Yes. With this HTML code 
    '<form [formGroup]="productForm" (ngSubmit)="storeCategoryList()">'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the signature of `storeCategoryList()` to an arrow function to maintain [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471975/how-can-i-preserve-lexical-scope-in-typescript-with-a-callback-function) to the outer class as you are calling the method from within the modal:

```
storeCategoryList = () => {
  // your existing code
}
```

Hopefully that helps!