# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSubmit' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui for designing UI framework

```
     function handleSubmit(){
                alert("success");
            }
            function SignIn(props) {
            const { classes } = props;
            handleSubmit();
            return (<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>
                  <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
                  <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
                  </FormControl>
</form>
```

**Error Stack**

```
                    60 | <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                61 |   Sign in
                62 | </Typography>
                > 63 | <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>
                    | ^  64 |   <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                65 |     <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
                66 |     <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
```

Can anyone lemme know where m going wrong?
                        `

Comment: The problem might be in the backtick in the "return (`<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>" line. Can you try removing that and seeing if it works then? Also, you're referring to "this.handleSubmit", which doesn't exist in  functional component.

Comment: nope i.e., its a typo theirs nothing such my bad  as tactics . actually i'm not sure of how to call it in functional component

Comment: See my answer below. You can't have handlers in a functional component, you need to refactor it to a class component. Check out the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here:

1. You're calling `handleSubmit()` inside a functional component. That should only be called by your form
2. The handler function shouldn't be called in `onSubmit`. Use `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` instead of `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}`.
3. When using functional components (instead of a class), there's no `this` object, so no `this.props` either.
4. If using handling functions, then you should use a class. See the example below.

   ```
   class SignIn extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);

       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }

     handleSubmit = function(){
        alert("success");
     }

     render() {
       const { classes } = this.props;

       return (<form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
           <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
           <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
         </FormControl>
        </form>);
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with -

```
onSubmit={()=> this.handleSubmit()}
```

I think the problem is definitely going to be a [Lexical scoping in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471975/how-can-i-preserve-lexical-scope-in-typescript-with-a-callback-function)

Comment: actually the error disappered but when i click on singin the handlesubimt error doesnt render