# Typescript: this is not pointing to the class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using ionicframework together with TypeScript. When I create a modal object as seen below, the modal object is created successfully but inside the callback where it says this.$scope.modal = modal; **this** is referencing the browser window and hence the $scope is undefined. How can I get **this** to point to the class?

```
export class MyCtrl {
    constructor(private $scope: any, private $ionicModal) {

        // Load the modal from the given template URL
        this.$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('MyApp/myModal.html', (modal) => {
            this.$scope.modal = modal;
        }, {
                // Use our scope for the scope of the modal to keep it simple
                scope: this.$scope,
                // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, the `this` inside a lambda doesn't have the traditional behavior of `this` in JavaScript.  If you look at the compiled JS it will be clear what's happening, but basically it will usually be a level higher than you'd expect - in your case the window object.

The easiest way to work around this is to do a `var self=this;` above the line with the comment and then reference `self` in your lambda, or else just use normal function syntax such as `function(modal) {` which preserves the traditional functionality of `this` from JS.

Dan Quirk answered a similar question that I had here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1655

You may also wish to take a look at this: [Can I access the other this in a TypeScript lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934070/can-i-access-the-other-this-in-a-typescript-lambda)

Answer (score 3):

If you call something like `new MyCtrl($myScope, $ionicModal)`, references to `this` will correctly point to the new instance of `MyCtrl`.

What I suspect is that you're passing the `MyCtrl` class into a place where Angular expects a function, not a class!

Your code actually fails unhelpfully late due to a confusing aspect of JavaScript, namely that constructors can be (mis)used as normal functions without using `new`, in which case `this` will point to something higher up.

The solution is to use a normal function instead of a class, try:

```
function myCtrl($scope: any, $ionicModal) {

    // Load the modal from the given template URL
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('MyApp/myModal.html', (modal) => {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    }, {
            // Use our scope for the scope of the modal to keep it simple
            scope: $scope,
            // The animation we want to use for the modal entrance
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        });
```